# Calling a normal(.asmx) web service in windows phone 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Callling a normal web service in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967752/callling-a-normal-web-service-in-wp7)

I am new to Windows phone 7 development.

I have normal .NET web service(like http://test/TestService.asmx).

I have added this service to my WP7 Project using Service Reference (right clicking on solution, there i have a option called Add Service Reference and i have given my URL to add Service Reference) in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone. Normally we will add the WCF services using Add Service Reference option but here i added normal Web Service using Add Service Reference option.

For example I have Service like this:

```
public class Service1
    {
        //local variable
        public int aaa;

        //I have two functions like below:
        [WebMethod]
        public int Fun1()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public int Fun2()
        {
            // some calculations
            return aaa;
        }
    }
```

I am calling the methods like this in WP7:

```
Class AModel
{
     public void CreateT()
        {
           RS.Service1SoapClient objRS = new RS.RSService1SoapClient();
            objRS.Fun1Completed += new EventHandler<RS.Fun1CompletedEventArgs>(objRS_Completed);
            objRS.Fun1Async();
        }

    private void objRS_Completed(object sender, EventCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
             string str = e.Result;
             responseEventArgs = new ResponseEventArgs();
                responseEventArgs.response = e.Result;                
                System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(responseEventHandler, responseEventArgs);
        } 
}
```

Here i am able to get the Result Successfully for Fun1. But i have a one more function(Fun2) in same service which is using Service class variables(like variable called aaa in Fun2). Here i am getting my Service class with the name as 
ServiceSoap1Client and i have created the object for that class (in wp7) in CreateT() function, but this ServiceSoap1Client does not have the variable called aaa.
but ServiceSoap1Client class has the function Fun2Async() and event Fun2Completed.

I have added same service using Add Web Reference in visual studio 2010.

Here i am getting my Service class with same name and i have created object for that Class, here i am able get that variable aaa But same variable i am not able get in Wp7.

**My questions are:**

1. I have added normal web service using Service Reference (right clicking on solution, there i have a option called Add Service Reference and i have given my URL to add Service Reference). Is it Right?
2. If above method is a right way how can i get that variable aaa?
3. If above method is not a right way how can i call the  normal web service in WP7?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.